# What are the prerequisites for jitsi-meet?

Tags: jitsi, raspberry-pi4

I currently try to install jitsi-meet on a raspberry but don't succeed.

I tried to use Rasperian and Ubuntu Server as base OS.

I installed Java and nginx as prerequisites (as noted [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-your-own-video-conference-using-jitsi-meet-on-ubuntu-1804/)).

But I still always get to following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# apt install jitsi-meet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jitsi-meet : Depends: jitsi-videobridge (= 1124-1) but it is not installable
              Depends: jicofo (= 1.0-481-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For fresh Jitsi installation recommended for Ubuntu 18.04 server. 
Server specification is :- **4 GB Memory, 2 CPU and 20GB SSD hard disk** 
After that, you have to enable these ports in the firewall,

1. 22 for SSH
2. 80 for HTTP
3. 443 for HTTPS
4. UDP 10000-20000 for media traffic

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the reason - there are no packages for arm based systems:

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/1884

Comment: This is actually getting closer to not being the case.  Native code was moved out of the newest JVB version, and we have people contributing builds for other platforms where we _do_ have native code (namely `jitsi-sctp` and `jtisi-srtp`).  `jitsi-sctp` is no longer strictly necessary, though, as you can configure the bridge to use websockets instead of datachannels.